# Closing Infobox fires click event on map, immediately reopening infobox

Tags: bing-maps

I'm trying to add an Infobox to a map. When a user clicks on the map, they should see the info box, with the option of clicking the close icon when they are finished.

If the user clicks close in the infobox though it fires the click event on the map, which reopens the infobox again??

How do I resolve this, currently Im using the following

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(mymap, 'click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.targetType == 'map') {
    myinfobox.setOptions({visible:true}) ;
  }
}
```

Thanks, jebw

Comment: can you share some more complete code so we can test and fix quicker?

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful to you:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(mymap, 'click', function(ev) {
    if (ev.targetType== 'pushpin') {
        myinfobox.setOptions({visible:true});
    }
}
```